# How do I access the 2D points rendered by direct3D?

Tags: direct3d

This is my first direct3d program. I'm not even aware of keywords to search for. I have set up a simple 3D world and a camera. I need to get hold of the actual pixel coordinates rendered for a given camera position. I also need to know which 3D points, the points in screen-space map to.
As of now, my code calls:

```
device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, vertexBuffer.VertexCount, 0, indexBuffer.IndexCount / 3);
```

and this call is a blackbox to me. My problem would be solved, if this call would just return a list of 2D points in screen space that correspond to the vertices that I'm passing to it.

If there is no way of doing what I'm looking for, what is the closest thing to this that I can get?

Answer (score 1):

For each vertex you are rendering, you can apply it with the world, view and projection matrix to get the protective points on the screen. By the way, why do you need the screen points?